# javascript two function call when empty text then stop while execute

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckTextboxBlank(){
if(document.getElementById("addntp").value==""){
alert("Add NTP server");

}
}
</script>

<input type="text" value="" id="addntp" />
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="CheckTextboxBlank();" /><br />
```

Here when I click on "add" button on "add ntp server", then my function `CheckTextboxBlank();` is called and I get a message "add ntp server" and process is continue.

But i want to stop the process here when there is empty text box

I use this text in form

```
<form id="datetimeform" name="datetimeform" method="post" action="datetimeconfig.php" style="margin:0;padding:0">
```

and also i call another function too when there is some text in add ntp server

Comment: _'process is continue'_ what process do you mean? Form shouldn't get submitted like this, since you use `type="button"`.

Comment: Your going to have to try to better explain your question, it is too difficult to understand your english.

Comment: Yeah, this question is kinda hard to parse. Can you restate this using better grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what you want.  Maybe this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckTextboxBlank() {
  if(document.getElementById("addntp").value=="")
  {
     return false;
  }
  else
  {
     callsomefunction();
     return true;
  }
}
</script>
```